# Сломал всю башку, помогите - светлые головы

Tags: java, java-stream

```
@Test
void findBooksByAuthorNameTest() {
    Page<Book> response = mainController.findBooksByAuthorName("рэй", PageRequest.of(0, 20));
    Assert.assertNotNull(response);
    List<Author> authors = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Book> books = response.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
    books.stream().filter(book -> book.getAuthors().addAll(authors));
    System.out.println(authors.size());
}
```

У меня есть коллекция в коллекции как мне правильно ее достать и положить в коллекцию своего типа, пытаюсь добавить методом addAll
но размер коллекции authors все равно 0. По-любому ошибка элементарная, но я уже всю голову сломал

Comment: у вас в классе Book есть коллекция типа Author и вы хотите получит коллекцию всех авторов?

Comment: именно так, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Реализовать так(разумеется, в классе book  должен быть геттер getAuthors(), который возвращает коллекцию типа Author):

```
List<Author> authors = books.stream()
        .flatMap(book -> book.getAuthors().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало!!!!)))))